# Binding an object to a datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have an `employee` class which contains an instance of a `person` class:

```
List<Employee> emp = (AdventureWorks.Employees.Select(n => n)).ToList();

showgrid.ItemsSource = emp;
showgrid.Columns.Clear();

DataGridTextColumn data_column = new DataGridTextColumn();
data_column.Binding = new Binding("Person=>FirstName");
data_column.Header = "First Name";

showgrid.Columns.Add(data_column);
```

How do I bind the field `firstname` inside the `person` object with the column `First Name`?

Comment: Why are you creating your bindings programmatically? Surely this would be much easier to achieve with XAML.

Comment: Ideally you should create Bindings in XAML and not in code. In fact your datagrid itself should be defined in XAML.

Comment: please choose your tags more carefully - no need to use 3 different C# tags

Comment: Actually If I define in XAML then my Columns would be fixed.

Comment: In my case It is decided on runtime that which column is to be created or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a public property for your class person in your employee class. eg.

```
public person MyPerson {get;set;}
```

then you can bind with "." in your bindings

```
data_column.Binding = new Binding("MyPerson.FirstName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in code you would do something like the one shown below :

```
    private void BindDataToGrid()
    {
        //Sample Data
        List<Employee> empList =new List<Employee>();        
        empList.Add(new Employee(){FirstName = "Rob", LastName="Cruise"});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Lars", LastName = "Fisher" });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Arbuckle" });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Toole" });

        DataGridTextColumn data_column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        data_column.Binding = new Binding("FirstName");
        data_column.Header = "First Name";
        showgrid.Columns.Add(data_column);

        data_column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        data_column.Binding = new Binding("LastName");
        data_column.Header = "Last Name";

        showgrid.Columns.Add(data_column);
        showgrid.ItemsSource = empList;
        showgrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }

    private class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: actually the Firstname and lastname field is inside the class person. Employee has the property of type person in it.